# Locating "black rectangles" on an image - language independent

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

I am writing a small image analysis program just for fun.  Image analysis has always fascinated me.  I am trying to locate regions on a scanned document.  These regions are going to be marked by clearly defined filled black rectangles (pre-printed on the page).

My problem is locating the rectangles.  I know SIFT\SURF find "features" but I am trying to find something specific.  Here is what I was thinking of doing.  I am not sure if this is the "right" way or there is a better idea.

First off using some library I will turn the image into greyscale, perhaps a PGM since that is what I'm used to working with in school.  For the analysis I first plan to run the image through a state of the art deskew algorithm in OpenCV or something else that I find.  Once I have my deskewed image I will then threshhold it at some pretty high thresshold.  The rectangles are going to be straight black hence me using a pretty high threshhold.  I will then experimentally determine a good size black rectangle to slide across the image.  While sliding my rectangle across the image I will determine the areas where the greatest percentage of pixles are the same.  I will have a cutoff, say 90%.  If 90% of the pixles contained in my window are black I must have found a rectangle.  My reasoning is that a true black rectangle slid over something that is "pretty much" a black rectangle is most likely a black rectangle.  Since I deskewed the image I can assume that the rectangles are straight up and down "enough".  I can then track the (x,y) offsets where the rectangles are found on the image and mark them.

Would anyone suggest a better approach?

Comment: Why don't you just use Hough Transform? The most common and simple approach to what you trying to do. There are many methods, but as a starter, I recommend you read up on Hough Transform. Feel me to ask if there are any problem regarding to Hough Transform that you don't understand. Cheers.

Comment: The Hough Transform is common but not simple.  Calling an existing library is simple, but since user3504779 is writing image analysis "just for fun" he/she will probably have more fun implementing algorithms instead of calling libraries.

Answer (score 2):

There are many approaches that *might* work. (One can easily come up with 10 or more approaches.)

---

#### Idea #1 - Canny edge detection; find rectangle fit to contours

- [cv::Canny](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=canny#canny)
- [cv::findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours)
- [cv::minAreaRect](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minarearect#minarearect), or
- [cv::boundingRect](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#boundingrect) might also work, *if* the deskewing works as advertised.

---

#### Idea #2 - Find all lines using Hough transform; Iterates through all regions created from line intersections.

---

#### Idea #3 - (Improvement on #2) Restrict the Hough transform to horizontal and vertical lines by pre-processing.

---

#### Idea #4 - Compute Horizontal and Vertical profiles on the entire image; find dips; iterate through all candidate regions.

This idea is based on the assumption that the black rectangles are large enough that they leave a "depression" in both the horizontal and vertical projection profiles, which would be detectable despite other noise objects in the image.

- [cv::reduce](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=reduce#reduce)

  - With `dim` = 0 or 1 for reducing to a row or column respectively,
  - With CV_REDUCE_AVG flag
- Apply [cv::threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold) to the horizontal and vertical projection profiles, separately.
- For each profile now thresholded into zero/non-zero, find runs of zeroes. These are the possible row ranges and column ranges that could contain the dark rectangles.
- For each combination of candidate row range and column range, calculate the average pixel value to decide if it is a true dark rectangle.

---

#### Idea #5 - Use integral image (summed area table) to quickly calculate the average pixel value in arbitrary rectangles

- [cv::integral](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=integral#integral)
- To compute the sum (and average) of a rectangle from an integral image, see the Wikipedia article on [Summed Area Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table)

---

#### Preprocessing idea - use morphological dilation (or erosion) to "erase" things that cannot be the large continuous black box.

---

#### Preprocessing idea - use pre-processing to enhance horizontal and vertical edges; suppress edges in other directions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is a better approach, but the first thing that came to mind would be a scan-line solution (assuming black or white pixels):  I'd check each scanline from top to bottom.  In each scanline I'd check each pixel from left to right.  A "first" black pixel would be a possible upperleft corner of a rect.  If there were enough following contiguous black pixels on the line to meet my desired minimum width, keep the [left, width] in a list of possible rects.  Find all possible rect starts and widths on the line.

For a rect to stay in the list and grow in height, the next scanline would have to have the same [left, width] occurrence, otherwise the rect is finished (if its height meets my desired minimum height) or discarded or ignored as too short in height.

You can easily add logic for situations like two rectangles too close to one another vertically or horizontally.  Overlapping rectangles would be trickier but still possible to detect with added code.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
for s := 1 to scanlinecount do
  begin
  pixel := 1
  while pixel <= scanlinewidth do
    if black(s, pixel) then // possible rect
      begin
      left := pixel
      repeat
        inc(pixel)
      until (pixel > scanlinewidth) or white(s, pixel)
      width := pixel - left
      if width >= MINWIDTH then // wide enough
        rememberrect(s, left, width) // bumps height if already in list
      end
    else inc(pixel)
  end
```

Your list of found rects stores the starting scanline, leftmost pixel, width, and height for each rect found.  The "rememberrect" routine checks each rect in the list:

```
rememberrect(currentline, left, width):
for r := 1 to rectlist.count do
  if rectlist[r].left = left
   & rectlist[r].width = width
   & rectlist[r].y + rectlist[r].height = currentline then
     begin // found rect continuing on scanline
     inc(rectlist[r].height)
     exit
     end
inc(rectlist.count) // add new rect to list
rectlist[rectlist.count].left := left
rectlist[rectlist.count].width := width
rectlist[rectlist.count].y := currentline
rectlist[rectlist.count].height := 1
```

If the group of black pixels on the current scanline has the same leftmost pixel and width as a group on the previous scanline (you'll know they're vertically contiguous because the starting scanline of the rect in the list plus its height will equal the current scanline) then rememberrect bumps the height of the found and remembered rect by 1.  Otherwise, remember the new rect with initial height 1.

After the last scanline you'll have a long list of rect candidates, many of them only 1 pixel high.  Delete or ignore any rects in the list that aren't high enough.  To avoid growing a long list of futile candidates: at the start of each scanline mark all rects found so far as "finished".  If rememberrect grows an existing rect or adds a new rect, mark that rect as "grown".  At the end of each scanline, any rect still marked as finished that isn't tall enough can be deleted from the list.

Comment: That is a good idea.  How do most vision guys determine what "enough" is?  Do they usually just experiment and tweak their threshholds until they find a sweet spot.  With your algorithm I'm thinking I should allow a gap of one or two pixels to still count as "contigious" as I wouldn't want a single white pixel due to error throw the whole rectangle off.

Comment: You said "clearly defined filled black rectangles" but you can programmatically add whatever fuzziness you wish to support. A black rect with 1 white middle pixel would scan as 4 rects with the code above: 1 big top rect, 1 big bottom rect, and 2 one-line rects on each side of the pixel. You could ignore any pixel while scanning if it's only 1 white surrounded by black (or vice versa), or you could allow the 4 rects then do postprocessing on the rect list to combine contiguous rects. Eg, all 4 rects align on at least 2 sides so combine them as 1 rect using their outermost boundaries.